# How to set dynamic variable once it is identified to all recipes in a cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I need a help to set a global variable in chef recipes.
I have below series of recipes:

1. Discovers the tomcat from path variable/attibutes/default.rb:
   default['tomcat_cookbook']['tomcathome']="['/home/tomcat','/home/ApacheTomcat']"
   This recipe will identify the tomcat installation as either one of the directory will be available on server out of this two directories.

Lets say, if it sets the tomcathome to directory "/home/tomcat", I have some more subsequent recipes like start/stop/restart tomcat.

Currently for every recipe I am running discovery logic inside stop/start recipes while knowing that on a particular server, tomcathome is set to "/home/tomcat" .

Is there any way I can remove duplicate code for tomcat home discovery and make use of the identified tomcathome variable for remaining recipes.
Please suggest.

Comment: What you have displayed as *Discovers the tomcat from path*, is the attribute, what/where is the logic to choose one of these? You should update the question with the relevant code to make it answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a good use of libraries. I'll assume the cookbook name is `tomcat_cookbook`. In the `libraries` folder in a cookbook, create a file called `path.rb`.

Add the following code into the `path.rb` file. I prefer to namespace my libraries to organize my methods using CookbookName::ModuleName format.

**libraries/path.rb:**

```
module TomcatCookbook
  module Path
    
    def install_path
      node['tomcat_cookbook']['tomcathome'].each do |path|
        return path if ::Dir.exist?(path)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Within any recipe, you can include this module and use the methods in it:

```
# Use this include for use in the recipe
Chef::Recipe.send(:include, TomcatCookbook::Path)

# Use this include for using methods in the directory resource itself
Chef::Resource::Directory.send(:include, TomcatCookbook::Path)

Chef::Log.info("Install Path: #{install_path}")

directory "tomcat_install_path" do
  path install_path
  action :create
end
```

In certain situations, I have needed to create a common cookbook which includes only libraries which I can use across multiple cookbooks.